# Power rules: $x ^ {(y^z)}$

Tags: exponentiation, power-towers

I know about $(x^y)^z$ = $x^{yz}$ but what about $x^{(y^z)}$? Are there any rules for this?

Let's consider the power of power rule: $(x^y)^z$ = $x^{yz}$:

> $(2^3)^4$ = $8^4$ = 4096
>
> $2^{3\times 4}$ = $2^{12}$ = 4096

But same can't work for $x^{(y^z)}$. Is there really no rule for this?

I'm not good with calculus so I didn't check those discussions really. If there is such a rule, please explain it.

Comment: There is no such rule.

Comment: Just FYI, $2$ is a misleading number in that sense. I'd recommend not using $2$ because it might lead you to believe things that are not true. Not only for exponentials.

Comment: @BrianBlumberg: Reminiscent of Richard Guy's Strong Law of Small Numbers.

Comment: @BrianBlumberg & BrianTung, power of power is a proven rule. Besides, I'm not a math person. The Strong Law is a nice read though.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you consider "a rule". There are many ways to calculate with things, from which many rules stem. One not unimportant rule would be
$$ x^{(y^z)} = (x^y)^{(y^{z-1})} = ((\ldots(x^y)^y)\ldots)^y $$
This will matter if you for example want to calculate such a power in some group. Suppose we have some element $x$ of some finite group (let’s say an elliptic curve) and suitable integers $y,z$ and we want to calculate $x^{(y^z)}$. Then $y^z$ might be so large that it does not fit into memory. But instead of calculating $y^z$ we can turn the whole thing into taking $z$ times the $y$th power.